# Can't fetch the data in MVC by ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to fetch data from a database in ASP.NET MVC with Ajax.

This is my controller:

```
public JsonResult EditCustomer(int Id)
{
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        { 
            using (SEntities dc = new SEntities())
            { 
                customer = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.ID == Id).SingleOrDefault();
                customer.Events = null;
            }
        }

        return Json(customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and this is the Ajax in the view

```
var EditCustomer = function (Id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/BasicInfo/EditCustomer',
        data: { 'Id': Id },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#txtFirstName').val(data.FirstName);
            $('#txtLastName').val(data.LastName);
            $('#txtPhone').val(data.Phone);
            $('#txtID').val(data.ID);
            $('#hdUserID').val(data.UserId);
            $('#txtNote').val(data.ClientNote);
            $("#myModalEdit").modal("show");

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Failed EditCustomer');
        }
    })
}
```

Although the variable customer from controller is correctly populated but in the view I just get the error "Failed EditCustomer".

What could cause this problem?

Comment: "customer from controller is correctly populated" how do you it? Did you check developer tools of browser? What error is there?

Comment: @Serge: I trace it , in controller I can trace the customer variable and it is populated with the customer data, but when it enters in  view , in enters the error function and alert('Failed EditCustomer'); pops up

Comment: Did you check browser "console" ?

Comment: @Serge: if I set the Console.log(response) in error section of ajax, I recieve the  this : jquery-2.1.1.js:8623 POST http://localhost:50869/BasicInfo/EditCustomer 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It usually means an error inside of EditCustomer action. Try a postman. it usually gives the best error description. Only remove Request.IsAjaxRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just  by adding

```
 dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

before fetching data in controller. and it worked.